# Pandas dataframe custom columns and rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have been stuck here I don't know why but this is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import random as R
n = int(input("How many columns : "))
list1 = []
list2=[]
nilaiRand = R.randint(1,30)
for i in range(0,n):
    print("Column-",i+1 ,sep="",end=": ")
    kolom = input()
    list1.append(kolom)
print(list1)
ind = int(input("Total random number : "))
inde = range(1,ind+1)
list2.append(nilaiRand)
print(list2)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list1,list2)
```

'list1' is the name of the columns, 'list2' is the random number which is the rows.

I need to input how many columns you want to make,and it will request the name of each columns and listed in 'list1'. and I want to make the rows as much as `ind = int(input("Total random number : "))` and the fill of the line is random number `nilaiRand = R.randint(1,30)`

The output should be like

```
How many columns : 3
Column-1 : Eli
Column-2 :Chick
Column-3 :You
Total random number : 4

Result 

   Eli   Chick   You
1   12    22       3
2   21    12       11
3   4     11       21
4   13    14       5
```

Any solution?

Comment: will you state in the first paragraph what the code is suppose to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
import random as R
n = int(input("How much columns: "))
dict1 = {}
for i in range(0,n):
    column = input()
    dict1[column] = []
ind = int(input("Number of rows: "))
for column in dict1.keys():
    for _ in range(ind):
        dict1[column].append(R.randint(1,30))
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

Input:

- 5
- A
- B
- C
- D
- E
- 8

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   21  1   6   1   1
1   21  18  17  3   5
2   25  3   6   17  23
3   5   8   16  25  23
4   6   16  22  30  27
5   25  17  14  11  13
6   13  26  30  24  11
7   4   21  29  14  2
```

However, please up your question-writing game. [Do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Also give a clear desired output and tell us at what point in your code you stumble unto problems.

##### Update

If you want to start your index at 1, try:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=range(1, ind+1))
```

Comment: it works,thanks,i just need to make the index start from 1

Comment: See my update: `dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=range(1, ind+1))`

Comment: yes,already solved thank you for helping